# При запуски Телеграм бота ошибка - ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Здорова всем.
Решил научится разбираться в **bot_telegram** выбрал библиотеку (**aiogram**) для создания бота.

При использовании **Python 3.7** вроде как работало но пришлось перейти на **Python 3.8** одна часть функционала бота не работала на **Python 3.7**.

*Anaconda (version 1.7.2)*
*Python (version 3.8.5)*

**Вывод с консоля.**

```
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dus/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 359, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(limit=limit, offset=offset, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/dus/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/dus/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 162, in request_timeout
    self._ctx_timeout.reset(token)
ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='TelegramRequestTimeout' at 0x7f8229a70770> at 0x7f82298dee80> was created in a different Context
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Polling is stopped.
```

**Инициализация бота**

```
from config import API_TOKEN
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types 
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import keybords as kb 
from time import sleep
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import nest_asyncio


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token = API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())





nest_asyncio.apply()
class Form(StatesGroup):
    day = State()
    hour = State()
    minutes = State()
    

@dp.message_handler(commands=['alarm'])
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Plsm,input day for alarm")
    await Form.day.set()

 

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.day)
async def answerDay(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer_day = message.text

    await state.update_data(answer_day1 = answer_day )

    await message.answer("Plsm,input hour for alarm")
    await Form.hour.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hour)
async def answerHour(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer_hour = message.text


    await state.update_data(answer_hour1 = answer_hour )
    await message.answer("Plsm,input minutes for alarm")
    await Form.minutes.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.minutes)
async def answerMinutes(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()
    answer_day1 =  data.get("answer_day1")
    answer_hour1 = data.get("answer_hour1")
    answer_minutes = message.text    

datatime.now()
    while True :
        time_now = datetime.now()
        if str(time_now.hour) == answer_hour1  and str(time_now.minute) == answer_minutes and str(time_now.day) == answer_day1:
            await bot.send_message (message.chat.id, 'time to wake up')
            break
        sleep (1)
# 
    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('This bot help you set the alarm and use API for choice random music.'
                          ,reply_markup=kb.greet_kb)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['time'])   
async def time_now (message: types.Message):
    time = datetime.now()
    b = time.strftime('Time now is ' + '%H:%M:%S' + '\n' '%A,%d' + '\n'  '%B,  %Y')
    await message.answer(b)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help (message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(
        text = '''
        This telegram bot was created as an alarm clock that can search for random music and use it to awakening more easily.
        
        /time - show actual time and date now.             
        /alarm - help you set alarm. The format used is 24 hours.
        '''
          )
        
       
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

P.s Нет я не взялся за реальный проект, это всего лишь личная инициатива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подправил ваш код теперь он отлично работет, но у меня есть подозрения что это ваш anaconda творит чудеса, запустите просто обычным питоном.
Вот пофиксенный код:

```
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types 
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from time import sleep
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token = "HERE TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

class Form(StatesGroup):
    day = State()
    hour = State()
    minutes = State()
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['alarm'])
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Plsm,input day for alarm")
    await Form.day.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.day)
async def answerDay(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer_day = message.text

    await state.update_data(answer_day1 = answer_day )

    await message.answer("Plsm,input hour for alarm")
    await Form.hour.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.hour)
async def answerHour(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer_hour = message.text

    await state.update_data(answer_hour1 = answer_hour )
    await message.answer("Plsm,input minutes for alarm")
    await Form.minutes.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.minutes)
async def answerMinutes(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()
    answer_day1 =  data.get("answer_day1")
    answer_hour1 = data.get("answer_hour1")
    answer_minutes = message.text    

    while True :
        time_now = datetime.now()
        if str(time_now.hour) == answer_hour1 and str(time_now.minute) == answer_minutes and str(time_now.day) == answer_day1:
            await bot.send_message (message.chat.id, 'time to wake up')
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await state.finish()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('This bot help you set the alarm and use API for choice random music.')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['time'])   
async def time_now (message: types.Message):
    time = datetime.now()
    b = time.strftime('Time now is ' + '%H:%M:%S' + '\n' '%A,%d' + '\n'  '%B,  %Y')
    await message.answer(b)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def help (message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(
        text = '''
        This telegram bot was created as an alarm clock that can search for random music and use it to awakening more easily.
        
        /time - show actual time and date now.             
        /alarm - help you set alarm. The format used is 24 hours.
        '''
          )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[image: Скриншот работы бота]

Удачи!